# How much time my fresh app will remain supported by upcoming IOS version?

Tags: ios

I don't know if I am the only one to ask myself but I can't find answers.
I'm building an app for a customer and he asked me about maintenance in the next years, but how to know how long my app will stay compatible with the next versions of iOS?

Comment: Please enrich yourself with the many stack exchange forums. As you state, this is an out of scope question on SO.

Comment: This question is off topic because it is not about programming, but rather legal issues

Comment: I've voted to close as "opinion based", but it's probably closer to "unanswerable". I guess you'd have to invite Apple to make comments about planned system call deprecations prior to their making formal announcements for the same. There's no way they are going to agree to that.

Comment: So I can say my customer, "nobody can tell", even if it's not the best I expected it's still better than "I don't know"

Answer (score 1):

There is no answer as such to this question. However, there are steps you can take to maximize longevity/compatibility:

- write clean, well-documented, bug-free code (maintenance is not just about OS compatibility)
- use best practices to determine how to use the underlying OS calls (that is, the first time you write something using an unfamiliar API is not likely to be the best way to write that thing using that API except in trivial cases)
- Don't use deprecated calls (take the time to learn the "new way", or know that you will, at some point in the maintenance window, likely have to rewrite that code)
- limit your use of external code (open-source, third-party, etc) as these may have their own dependencies that you will need to accommodate
- acknowledge and understand the volatility of the parts of the OS you use in your app - some parts of the OS haven't changed substantially since the origins of the App Store - some are still new enough to change on each release. Plan accordingly to your specific case.
- choose a clean, simple issue tracker and use it aggressively so that you can identify patterns that may relate to reported issues. When you find something that is due to unexpected changes in the OS, be aggressive about re-applying these suggestions so that when you fix/rewrite the code, it stands the greatest chance of surviving.

Comment: This looks like good advice to me. Paradoxically, one should maintain the kinds of docs and issue tracking that would allow another dev to pick it up, even if a team/freelancer would like to keep the customer. In fact, I would say this practice can be used as a marketing device to the customer - if you use us, you are not welded to us for your future maintenance.

Comment: I'd add that if a customer is looking to have an app built without any maintenance, that is a recipe for difficulty. There are nearly always issues to address in a piece of software, and contracts should be worded such that ordinary bugs are not defects that should be fixed for free. A shared testing responsibility would probably help here.